# Throwable.initCause not found when using MySQL/JDBC in Android

Tags: java, android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci

Before yelling at me using a web interface, please note that I'm writing a **MySQL client app**, not a lazy app that tries to directly access a private common database.

I have properly added mysql-connector-java dependency (5.1.34) (through Maven) into the build.gradle script. It installs my app properly through Android emulator. However, when passing it to Travis-CI through [this template](https://github.com/codecov/example-android/blob/master/.travis.yml), errors such as failure to find `javax.*` classes emerge. OK, since this is Android, I can understand that `javax.*` classes might not be present. But I noticed this line that is very strange and I can't understand why:

> Warning: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAConnection: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.Throwable initCause(java.lang.Throwable)' in program class com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXAException

Why would a method from the Throwable be absent?

This is my `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "application.id.here"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
}
```

I am not sure which files would be relevant, so please leave a comment if there are any other files that are related to the problem.

[This is a log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9ac4bee03d5bc7ab24c6d9dfd29f0af8) of the warning messages when I click "Build APK" from Android Studio.

#### Finally...

I would also like to ask, is there a way to solve this problem to build an APK that includes the mysql-connector properly?

Comment: What does your initCause(somethingThrowable) show in your MysqlXAExcetpion class?

Comment: From JD-GUI it is like [this](https://transfer.sh/TBb8e/mysqlxaexception.png). No initCause found, but I saw a reference to a `javax.transaction.xa.XAException` class, which according to the error messages should be absent.

Comment: Also edited to add some extra information at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set `minifyEnabled` to `false` for `debug` `buildType` and `true` for `release` and then check that the related proguard rules are correct to keep the classes you are missing.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if your proguard file is already correct:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```